# Building a docker image for a node js application with private module

Tags: git, docker, npm, dockerfile, npm-install

I have a node js project that uses a private module. The module is added via git url and during development the same git ssh key is used as the one used for the main project. Running npm install works fine.

The problem I'm facing happens when I try to create a docker image because a different npm is running, therefore, git fails to authenticate.

Has anyone else faced a similar issue? How to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple solutions for this:

1. Download the dependencies outside of the Docker build phase and [COPY](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy) them in as part of the build. `COPY node_modules/ node_modules/`
2. Make your SSH key available within the Docker build context. You could use the [`--build-arg`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#set-build-time-variables---build-arg) option for passing that in, or `COPY` it into the image during build time.

There's pros and cons to both solutions but neither is necessarily *wrong*.